ASP.NET 4.8 Web API running in Docker Container - Access Denied Writing to Registry
I created an ASP.NET 4.8 Web API through Visual Studio and have it setup so it automatically creates a docker container. There's a 3rd party DLL as a reference in the project which is trying to update the registry but whenever it attempts to write to HKLM or HKCU, it throws this error:

Access to the registry key '{RegistryPath}' is denied

{RegistryPath} is just a placeholder for the actual path but it's erring on Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey.CreateSubKey.
When I run a whoami command on the container, I get this response:
user manager\containeradministrator

so I assume it would have permissions but I could be mistaken that the actual IIS it's running on is using a default account.
Is there a way to set the account for IIS on the docker container so it can actually write to the registry or is there something else I need to do?

have you tried iis-remote-management-for-docker-containers or Setting up IIS with User Authorization in Windows Server containers there are some comments about setting an account for iis

Thanks, I was able to get it to work!
